# How to add a stroke around an image?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

## Question

I have a `CGImageRef` image. It is actually a image which is going to be used as a mask. So, the "alpha layer" of it is what I really care about. I want to "thicken" the opaque part of the image, as if I would add a stroke around the opaque part. How to do that?

## More context

I have an image (a `CGImageRef`) like that:

[image]

It has been created by

```
    mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

I'm using it as a mask. The `UIView` under the mask is the same text. The problem is that the text underneath is not completed covered by the mask. See:

[image]

## More code

This code is in a `UILabel` subclass.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw text normally
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    if (self.alternativeTextColor) {
        CGImageRef mask = NULL;

        // Create a mask from the text
        mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.frame.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, (CGFloat) -1.0);

        // Clip the current context to our mask
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, mask);

        // Set fill color
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [self.alternativeTextColor CGColor]);

        // Path from mask
        CGPathRef path;

        if (CGRectIsEmpty(self.maskFrame)) {
            path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        } else {
            UIBezierPath *roundRectBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.maskFrame
                                                                           cornerRadius:self.maskCornerRadius];
            path = CGPathCreateCopy([roundRectBezierPath CGPath]);
        }

        CGContextAddPath(context, path);

        // Fill the path
        CGContextFillPath(context);
        CFRelease(path);

        // Clean up
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CGImageRelease(mask);
    }
}
```

## Link to the project

https://github.com/colasjojo/Test-NYSegmentedControl

Comment: Show the code that creates the word "Light" both in black in the background and in white in the foreground, and show how these views are created and positioned.

Comment: You are using the _word_ mask, and you are using a variable _name_ mask, but looking at your github project there is no actual mask. So you really should not be claiming that there's a mask here. There isn't.

Comment: @matt What about `CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, mask);`

Comment: But that's just a form of clipping while drawing. It isn't a _mask_ (i.e. a layer mask) in the normal sense of the term.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to clip to text, I'd suggest not doing it via an intermediate bitmap and instead clipping to the paths of the actual text as in the snippet below from SVGgh's GHText class:

```
            CGContextSaveGState(quartzContext);
            CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(quartzContext, kCGTextStrokeClip);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(quartzContext, strokeWidthToUse);
            ... Draw Text here ....
             CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(quartzContext);
            CGContextClip(quartzContext);
            ... Do clipped drawing here ...
            CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(quartzContext, kCGTextFill);
            CGContextRestoreGState(quartzContext);
```

This isn't answering your question, but it's probably what you should do instead. Play around with CGContextSetTextDrawingMode to get the effect you are going for.